# Using JSON to return a Java Map

Tags: java, json, dictionary

What's the best way to return a Java Map using the JSON format?
My specific need is a key -> value association between a date and a number.

My concern is this: My structure basically contains N elements of the same type (a mapping between a date and a number), and I want to be able to quickly iterate through them in Javascript.

In XML, I would have:

```
<relation date='mydate' number='mynumber'/>
<relation date='mydate' number='mynumber'/>
...
<relation date='mydate' number='mynumber'/>
```

and I would use jQuery like this:

```
$(xml).find("relation").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("date"); // the date
    $(this).attr("number"); // the number
})
```

It's my first experience with JSON and I would like to know if I can do something similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I haven't tried it myself, the [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) of the [Java implementation of JSON from json.org](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) has a [`JSONObject(Map)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.util.Map)) constructor.

Once a JSON object is created from the `Map`, then a JSON string can be obtained by calling the [`toString`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString()) method.

Comment: Yeah, that works (I have tried it too - although mainly with String -> String Maps)

Answer (score 0):

```
String myJson = "{ ";
for (String key : myMap.keySet())
    myJson += key + " : " + "'" + myMap.get(key) + "',";
myJson += " } ";
```

I leave the last comma because it wont give us many problems. The javascript just ignores it.

Well, this respond your question but I guess that won't help much. Try posting a more specific one.

Comment: Hmm... constructing the JSON string yourself when good libraries exist (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906530/using-json-to-return-a-java-map/906563#906563) isn't necessarily the *best* way, IMHO.

Comment: More importantly, this fails to produce correct JSON in some cases, e.g. when the strings contain ' characters. (And this would not be fixed by quoting also the key, which you don't do now.)